# OCR de cédula de identidad con TESSERACT

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract

Les cuento que estoy realizando un proyecto de reconocimiento de textos y todo funciona muy bien, hasta que quiero rescatar la información de la cédula de identidad.

Estoy usando **TESSERACT** para reconocer texto de una imagen TIFF.

```
 ExecuteMacCommand("tesseract -l " + sLanguage + " " + sTIFFFilePath + " " + sTXTFilePath);
                sText = FileToText(sTXTFilePath + ".txt");
                cleanFolderMac(sTIFFPath, ".tiff");
                cleanFolderMac(sTXTFPath, ".txt");
```

sLanguage:español(SP)

Ejemplo de cédula de referencia, que no representa una persona real, pero que si tiene el formato de la cédula de identidad chilena. Fuente: Registro Civil.

[image: Cédula de referencia. Persona ficticia]

fuente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dula_de_Identidad_(Chile)

Y no me reconoce nada de texto, otros documentos me reconoce super bien, pero no así la cédula. ¿Algún tip?

La función que uso para convertir los PDF a TIFF

```
 public static void PdfToTiff(string sPathPdf, string sPathTiff)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inicio Conversion a TIFF");
                GcPdfDocument doc = new GcPdfDocument();

                var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine("Resources", sPathPdf), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                doc.Load(fs, "");

                SaveAsImageOptions options = new SaveAsImageOptions();
                options.BackColor = Color.Black;

                //The tiff file must have high resolution
                options.Resolution = 30;
                
                //Set range for page
                int paginas = doc.Pages.Count;
                List<int> pages = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < paginas; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        pages.Add(i + 1);
                }

                doc.SaveAsTiff(sPathTiff, null, options);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle other web exceptions
                Console.WriteLine("No fue posible descargar el archivo a TIFF  Error: {1}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

He probado cambiando la resolución y el mismo resultado.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para exportar la imagen TIFF en blanco y negro?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Oye cuidado, estas haciendo publica la informacion de una persona, y stackoverflow se ve hasta en la estacion espacial internacional

Comment: hola, es una imagen de ejemplo , no representa una persona real

Comment: fuente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cédula_de_Identidad_(Chile) y tambien esta en el registro civil como ejemplo

Comment: pregunta editada y aclarada.

Comment: Creería que deberías [entrenar tesseract](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-ocr-with-tesseract-a4341e4564b6) para reconocer esa fuente en particular